# There is no element content in WS response. There is only a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in an upper element

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-ws

I use Java and Spring-ws for web services. 
I use contract first approach. So I generate the Jaxb Java classes.

In a xsd definition of ws service response I have this definition for element "Risk"

```
<xs:complexType name="Risk">
  <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:extension base="ns26311:Risk">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:group ref="ns26311:RiskData"/>
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

"ns26311:Risk" is defined in different XSD this way

```
<xs:complexType name="Risk" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
```

"ns26311:RiskData" is defined (in this different XSD) this way

```
<xs:group name="RiskData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="reRisk" type="ns29421:riskByEval" minOccurs="1"    maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

"ns29421:riskByEval" is defined in different XSD this way

```
<xs:simpleType name="riskByEval">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

---

And in the webservice XML response for element "reRisk" there is this fragment of code

```
<ns3:risk xsi:type="ns6:Risk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

And there is no element content in element "risk".

The fragment content of the element "risk" should look like this:

```
<ns2:risk>
  <ns13:reRisk>some value</ns13:reRisk>
</ns2:risk>
```

In a Java Jaxb objects (which represents the response) there is a value in the reRisk field.

Does anyone know why is not element reRisk filled in the response (and the is the weird 
xsi:type="ns6:Risk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" fragment of code in the XML response) ?

Thank you very much for your suggenstions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in a different place.

When I set the Risk property of the whole Java response object by myBatis I set different type of object to this property (from different package).

That's why I get the weird response in XML :-)